# Is there a tool to test iOS apps on a Mac without access to source code?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, testing, mobile

I'd like to be able to test an app that's available in the iOS App Store from my Mac. I don't have access to the source code. Is there any method/program for being able to do this?

Is there any way I transfer the app from an iOS device to my mac and run that app on xCode?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you not considering any jailbreaks then no :(

Comment: Shucks :( Thanks for the response!